# Rake error running task: "undefined method 'Task' for main:Object rake 0.9.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to run an example task that I wrote.
I've placed the file that contains the code under `lib/tasks` and named it `test.rake`.

The task code is:

```
Task :sayHello do
    puts "Hello World"
end
```

When I'm trying to run it I get the following error:

```
/lib/tasks/test.rake:2:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `Task' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I've tried to run "tools-> Run Rake Task" but I can't find my task within the given tasks. In addition, when I invoke `rake -T` from the console, my task is not listed.

I googled this error but all the related errors I see occurred in rake 0.9.0.0 and not in 0.9.2.2

I tried to put in inside a namespace and that causes the following error:

```
undefined method `namespace' for main:Object
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `task` (i.e. a method), not `Task` (i.e. a class). You have to define your task like

```
task :sayHello do
    puts "Hello World"
end
```

This matters because Ruby is always case sensitive.

Comment: I changed it a while ago and now I get the same error with 'task': in `<top (required)>': undefined method `task' for main:Object (NoMethodError) 
from -e:1:in `load' 
from -e:1:in `<main>'

Comment: It was this after all, you were right. I had another file with another capitalized 'Task'... thanks.